# Code name and worksheet name in Microsoft excel object

Tags: excel, vba

I am using prepared VBA code which I downloaded from the internet the code needs some changes to get what I need, one of them is to use the same name for the code and the sheet in Microsoft Excel objects, as shown in the attached picture.

How can I use the same name for the code and the sheet because I can't stop getting the following message **"Invalid property value"** when I use the same name for both the code and the sheet knowing that I saw many times that we can use the same name.

[image]

Comment: What name are you trying to use?

Comment: This is certainly possible. Except the case when the chosen code name already exists. Otherwise, your code should have another problem. Without seeing it, it is difficult to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: "many times that we can use the same name", but not always, for example, the codename can't contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Since we could not see the code you use, please try the next `Sub`:

```
Private Sub ChangeCodeName(sh As Worksheet, strCodeName As String)
  Dim shCModule As Object
  Set shCModule = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(sh.CodeName)
  shCModule.Name = strCodeName
End Sub
```

It should be called in the next way:

```
Sub testFunctionChangeCodeName()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Set sh = Worksheets("mySheet") 'of course, this sheet name must exist...
    ChangeCodeName sh, sh.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Code Names to Names and Vice Versa

- Every sheet code name, except the reserved keyword `history`, **is** a valid sheet name.
- On the other hand, every sheet name **is not** a valid sheet code name.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub CodeNamesToNamesTEST()
    CodeNamesToNames ThisWorkbook
End Sub

Sub CodeNamesToNames( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook)
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Const Dummy As String = "ZZZZ"
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sh As Object
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        dict(sh.Name) = sh.CodeName
    Next sh
    
    Dim proj As Object: Set proj = wb.VBProject
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim oName As String
    Dim nName As String
    Do
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            If StrComp(Key, dict(Key), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then ' match
                dict.Remove Key
            Else ' not a match
                oName = dict(Key)
                On Error Resume Next
                proj.VBComponents(oName).Name = Key
                Select Case Err.Number
                Case 0
                    dict.Remove Key ' successfully renamed
                Case 32813 ' code name is taken
                    n = n + 1
                    nName = Dummy & n
                    proj.VBComponents(oName).Name = nName
                    dict(Key) = nName
                Case 50132 ' invalid code name...
                    ' must start with [A-Za-z]
                    ' can only contain [A-Za-z0-9_]
                    dict.Remove Key ' ... cannot be renamed!
                End Select
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next Key
    Loop Until dict.Count = 0

End Sub


Sub NamesToCodeNamesTEST()
    NamesToCodeNames ThisWorkbook
End Sub

Sub NamesToCodeNames( _
        ByVal wb As Workbook)
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Const Dummy As String = "#$%"
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sh As Object
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        dict(sh.CodeName) = sh.Name
    Next sh
    
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim oName As String
    Dim nName As String
    Do
        For Each Key In dict.Keys
            If StrComp(Key, dict(Key), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then ' match
                dict.Remove Key
            ElseIf StrComp(Key, "history", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' reserved...
                dict.Remove Key ' ... cannot be renamed!
            Else ' not a match
                oName = dict(Key)
                On Error Resume Next
                wb.Sheets(oName).Name = Key
                If Err.Number = 0 Then ' successfully renamed
                    dict.Remove Key
                Else ' name is taken, rename the existing sheet
                    If dict.Exists(oName) Then
                        n = n + 1
                        nName = Dummy & n
                        wb.Sheets(oName).Name = nName
                        dict(Key) = nName
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next Key
    Loop Until dict.Count = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Friendly hint: Think you have duplicated code fragements in your post; btw some explanatory remarks to the code logic behind would be instructive for not so experienced users. @VBasic2008

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is fixed when I changed the name of the module POS to POS_Macros, I was using the same name for both the module and sheet code, I think we shouldn't use the same name for the module and the sheet code name related to a worksheet.

[image]